# Where to insert the filtering logging mechanism when using Boost.Log V2 module?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I have a project organized as follows:

[image]

All the "component" folders have the same structure. I am using the Boost.Log v2, and I am able to see all types of logs (trace, debug, ..., fatal) on the console, when I use them. I would like to use the very basic filtering mechanism shown in the documentation:

[image]

Here, a function "init" is called to perform the filtering. My question is: where is the correct place to put this filtering, in the case of my project, in such a way it will be valid everywhere in the project itself and if I need to change the default severity I would need to modify the code in just one place? Do I need like a configuration file where to put it? I was thinking to put it in every main.cpp inside every component but I think there are best solutions to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `main` function per process. You need to initialize logging, including filtering, early in that function.

If your project has multiple different executables then each executable has its own `main` function and you need to perform logging initialization in each of them. If you want to avoid code duplication, you can move the initialization to a common header and/or library that you would use in each of the executables. For example, move the `init` function from your code snippet to a separate header and include and use it in every `main` function.

You can use [settings files](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.settings_file) with Boost.Log, but that is entirely unrelated to code organization.